# Orthogonal basis in 2-dimensional vector spaces

Tags: vector-spaces, finite-fields, orthonormal, bilinear-form, characteristics

Let $V$ be a $2$-dimensional vector space over a finite field $F_p$. Given a non-degenerated symmetric bilinear form, what may I ask to $F_p$ to guarantee that there exists an orthogonal basis of $V$?

My intuition sais that $p\neq 2$, but I don't know how to prove that (although it seems trivial or straight by contradiction).

Comment: I'm not convinced that orthonormality is a viable concept over a finite field.

Comment: I would mean orthogonal

Comment: Are you familiar with the proof that there's an orthonormal basis for euclidean/unitary vector space and the Gram-Schmidt process? It goes like this

Let $\dim{V} = n$.
For $n=1$ you surely find a orthogonal basis for $V$.

Now assume you have an orthogonal basis $u_1,...,u_n$ for an $n$-dim subspace $V_n$ of $V$ and a basis $v_1,...,v_{n+1}$ of $V$ such that $V_n = \text{span}\{v_1,..,v_n\}$. Define
$$
u_{n+1} = v_{n+1} - \sum_{k=1}^n \langle v_{n+1}, u_k \rangle u_k,
$$
then

Comment: $$
\langle u_{n+1}, u_j \rangle = \langle v_{n+1} - \sum_{k=1}^n \langle v_{n+1}, u_k \rangle u_k, u_j\rangle = \langle v_{n+1}, u_j \rangle - \sum_{k=1}^n \langle v_{n+1}, u_k \rangle\langle u_k, u_j \rangle = \langle v_{n+1}, u_j \rangle - \sum_{k=1}^n \langle v_{n+1}, u_k \rangle \delta_{kj} = \langle v_{n+1}, u_j \rangle - \langle v_{n+1}, u_j \rangle = 0.
$$
Thus $u_1,...,u_{n+1}$ is an orthogonal basis for $V$. I don't see where this'd break for a finite field?